# Set Routing in ElasticSearch using NEST and Attribute Mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

I am trying to setup my mapping using [Attribute based mapping](http://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/indices/put-mapping.html)

I need to set routing, making it required and set to a particular property on my object that I am indexing.

Is this possible?  Has anyone accomplished this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `IdProperty` property of the `ElasticType` attribute:

```
[ElasticType(Name = "mydocument", IdProperty = "docDate")]
public class MyDocument
{
    [ElasticProperty(Name = docDate)]
    public DateTime DocDate { get; set; }

...
```

This sets the value stored against the `_id` field in elasticsearch, which is used for [routing](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-routing-field.html).

Comment: This solution is not part of NEST latest API

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to make the routing required when you are creating your index, like this:

```
client.CreateIndex("my-index",
    d => d
        .Mappings(mapping => mapping
            .Map<MyObject>(map => map
                .RoutingField(routing => routing
                    .Required(true))
                .AutoMap()
            )
        ));
```

Second, you need to add the routing value when you index your document, like this:

```
var result = client.Index<MyObject>(
        myObject,
        selector => selector
            .Id(myObject.ObjectId)/*to avoid "random" ids*/
            .Routing(routingValue)); //or in your case, myObject.MySpecialProperty
```

Finally, you need to specify the routing value(s), when you are doing a search.

```
client.Search<MyObject>(query => query.Query(q => q.MatchAll()).Routing(routingValue));
```

**Using NEST v2.4**